# Update column according to images path and name

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update column `img` so each cell has the value of one img path/name inside `images` folder.

```
$path = "../images/";
$items = glob($path . '*.jpg');
foreach($items as $img) { 

$db->query("update posts set img ='" . $img . "'");
```

Result - all cells have identical content !

Any help?

Comment: You would need a where clause to tell it which row to update. Your SQL statements tells it to update all rows.

Comment: If you only want to update one record, you need a `WHERE` clause with the ID (or some other unique identifier for that record). Otherwise, the database doesn't know what record you intend to update.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I want to update entire column, i.e. each cell but with a different single img path

Comment: I'm not really getting what you're actually trying to do. Your current script loops through a folder and updates _all_ records per iteration (file), which means that in the end, all records will only have the last file. How do you know what file belongs to what record? Could you give some example of what the db looks like before the update and what it suppose to look like after?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, the goal is that each cell have a different value of different img. It doesn't matter what cell and what img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first get all the post id's so you can update them one by one.

Here's some psuedo code. It would probably need some modification (at least the first part where you get all the post id's):

```
// Get all post ids
// Change the database call to match your db library
$ids = $db->query("select id from posts");

$i = 0;
foreach (glob('../images/*.jpg') as $img) {
    if (!array_key_exists($i, $ids)) {
        // There's no more ids, so let's stop the loop
        // and consider the script to be done.
        break;
    }

    // Update one record with one image
    $db->query("update posts set img = '{$img}' where id = " . $ids[$i]['id']);

    // Increment the index so we will get the next
    // post id during the next iteration.
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `where` clause in your query to filter the results before updating the contents.
example

```
update post set img = 'your_image_path.png' where post_id='your_post_id';]
```

Read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm) for more info